# using class local type definition in constructor declaration

Tags: c++11, templates, using-directives

I am trying to use a class local type definition in a constructor declaration. both the classes are templates, here is the code.

```
template < typename T>
class complexType
{
    public:
    using value_type = T;
    complexType( T t ) {}
};


template <typename containedType >
class container
{
    public:
    container ( containedType::value_type v ) { return; }
    //container ( int v ) { return; }
};

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    container <complexType<int>> c(100);
    return 0;
}
```

if i use the second constructor definition which is being passed an int, the code builds fine. i cannot reason why the code won't build.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value_type` is dependent name, which depends on template argument, in such case you need to use `typename` to indicate that `value_type` is *type*:

```
template <typename containedType >
class container
{
    public:
    container ( typename containedType::value_type v ) { return; }
                ^^^^^^^ 
    //container ( int v ) { return; }
};
```

Comment: Thanks alot it worked like a charm. need to do more research on this typename